# Что такое метки классов(нейронная сеть)

Tags: нейронные-сети, искусственный-интеллект, классификация

Переворошил уже пол интернета, но все ещё не уверен, что значит термин "метки классов" в нейронной сети (классификация)...

Вроде как это список ВСЕХ выходных нейронов(ответов): (например если нейронка отличает кота от собаки, у нее будут только две метки классов: кот и собака (точнее числа, по которым это определяется) ), или же это просто **правильные** ответы для **обучения** нейронной сети (например даны несколько изображений для той же нейронки, и у них в названии написано, кот это или собака).

Получилось запутанно, но надеюсь понятно.

Буду очень признателен за ответ!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метки классов (labels) - это именно наименования классов. Для примера с котами и собаками - это столбец данных или список, состоящий из этих двух значений (`кот` или `собака`).

В нейронную сеть подаются данные в числовом виде. Для этого обычно используют различные `encoders`. В итоге может получиться один столбец с цифрами, соответствующими уникальным классам или же [One-Hot Encoding](https://www.google.com/search?q=one+hot+encoding&pws=0&gl=us&gws_rd=cr).

Comment: Вот, только что хотел об этом спросить.
Спасибо большое!